# How to make a single mob go invisible (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft

I'm not sure if this is a command bug or not, but if I have one mob riding the other I can't make a single one invisible. Like if I want a mob to look like it's floating in the air, so I make the bottom mob invisible. The problem is both mobs go invisible, including the one on top. I've used programs like MC Stacker to no avail, any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are a programmer community. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You will find that your question doesn't really fit here and I am afraid you will need to find a different place to ask this question. But feel free to ask once you started coding.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:999999}], Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:<YOUR_MOB_NAME_HERE>"}]}
```

if that dosen't work, i'm not sure.